# How to transfer data to OPC server?

Tags: python, visual-studio, client-server, opc, opc-ua

I have written two programs, one in PYTHON and other in Visual C++ on my local computer. I want to transfer the respective output of these programs to OPC server. So that clients can access it from the explorer. Is there any library in python or in Visual studio, that can manipulate this problem? (preferably python)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you take a look at [this link](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua). It is a free and open source OPCUA stack written entirely in Python.